# Windows 10 - multiple screen with gap between them

Tags: windows-10, display

Recently, I started using Windows 10 with 2 screens. However, if a window is on both screens, there is a difference in the relative position between the monitor on the left and the monitor on the left.

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are both monitors the same make and model and same height? Same resolution? Same height of taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> system -> display.To fix the miss alignment go to display settings you will see a diagram of your screens move them so they are aligned [as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xperJ.png)